# Order Database Data in a CSV via fputcsv

Tags: php, laravel

I want data from my database in a **CSV**. My problem is the data is not ordered. In my **CSV** there is only one line with the data.

I want for every day a own column and for every hour a own row.

Like this :

```
-|1|2|3|4|5|6| *DAYS*
0|_|_|_|_|_|_|
1|_|_|_|_|_|_|
2|_|_|_|_|_|_|
3|_|_|_|_|_|_|
4|_|_|_|_|_|_|
5|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

My code is this :

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fputcsv($handle, ['customer_id', 'count', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']);

foreach ($table as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, [$row['customer_id'], $row['count'], $row['year'], $row['month'], $row['day'], $row['hour']]);
}
```

Comment: What do you want inside the cell? Customer_ID, count, or both?

Comment: @Adder I want inside the Cell the count.

Comment: What have you tried? From the code above it doesn't show that you've tried anything. I suggest making use of Arrays to build the structure you want, and then foreach loop to put them in CSV. Stack isn't here to do your work for you.

Comment: Can you show your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted your code. I added a preprocessing step, which creates a lookup table with indexes $hour and $day ($ymd). I hope it works, I didn't test it. It should give you an idea in any case.

```
$days = array();
$hours= array();
$ymds = array();
foreach ($table as $row) {
    if(strlen($row['month'])<2) $row['month'] = "0{$row['month']}";
    if(strlen($row['day'])<2) $row['day'] = "0{$row['day']}";
    $ymd = "{$row['year']}-{$row['month']}-{$row['day']}";
    $hour = $row['hour'];
    $count = $row['count'];
    if(!isset($ymds[$hour]) $ymds[$hour] = array() ;
    if(!isset($ymds[$hour][$ymd]) $ymds[$hour][$ymd] = 0;
    $ymds[$hour][$ymd] += $count;
    $days[$ymd]= $ymd;
    $hours[$hour]= $hour;
}
unset($row);

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fputcsv($handle, $days);

foreach ($hours as $hour) {
    $row = array();
    foreach ($days as $ymd) {
        $column = isset($ymds[$hour][$ymd]) ? $ymds[$hour][$ymd] : 0;
        $row[] = $column;
    }
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like below .

```
$filename = 'file.csv';
header( "Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename\"" );
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");   
$fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');

$header = array('customer_id', 'count', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour');
fputcsv($fp, $header);
foreach ($table as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```